# Function of [$] operator in system verilog in declaring objects of a class

Tags: system-verilog

what is the function of $ in the following code segment

className objects[$];

does it create an infinite number of objects?

Answer (score 0):

It creates a queue of class variables—it does not create any class objects. You have to push already created class objects onto the queue using another class variable that contains a handle to an object:

```
className objects[$];
className h;

h = new();
objects.push_back(h);
```

See section *7.10 Queues* of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM